# Unclosed string Angular CLI giving errors on content and more

Tags: css, angular

I've imported some styles from bootstrap theme to my angular 8 project and added them to angular.json but when I tries to compile them it crashes and it shows me the following error:

```
(7733:13) Unclosed string

  7731 |  }
  7732 | .accordion_wrapper .panel .panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
> 7733 |        content: "+";
       |              ^
```

If i remove all of these contents, it gives me error for `type="checkbox"`
CSS attached: https://jsfiddle.net/z8b9mvsy/

I've already tried to remove these content attributes but of no use

```
.accordion_wrapper .panel .panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content: "+";
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.handyman_sec1_wrapper input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share how you include the file in your angular.json? Do you include a .css file or a .less or .scss file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the CSS class `jp_regis_right_side_box_wrapper`. The implementation you shared in the JSFiddle is:

```
.jp_regis_right_side_box_wrapper{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    padding-top: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 170px;
    background:url('../images/content/condi_bg.jpg') 50% 0 repeat-y;
    background-position":center 0;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Notice the property `background-position":center 0;`. It has an invalid `"` character. You can even see it via syntax highlighting when the code is in this answer. It should be:

```
.jp_regis_right_side_box_wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 170px;
    background: url('../images/content/condi_bg.jpg') 50% 0 repeat-y;
    background-position:center 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

That invalid `"` character will cause issues across the entire file. I'd also recommend to put the CSS content into a validator such as https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator and make sure you resolve all other issues.